# Problems with AWS and angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, amazon-web-services

I'm working with AWS and angular.

AWS works fine if i have the code in the html file but when I move to an js file it doesn't work.

I have this code:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.1.43.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="myCtrl">
<div id="results"></div>
<input type="file" id="file-chooser" />
<button id="upload-button">Upload to S3</button>
<button ng-click = "listObjs()">Listar</button>
</body>
</html>
```

and for the js:

```
(function(){
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);   

    myApp.controller('myCtrl',['AWS','$scope', function myCtrl($scope, AWS){
    AWS.config.update({
    .......
```

The error that I get is ***Unknown provider: AWSProvider <- AWS <- myCtrl***

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

In your controller the dependency injection array has $scope and AWS out of order.

You have:

```
myApp.controller('myCtrl',['AWS','$scope', function myCtrl($scope, AWS){
AWS.config.update({
```

It should be:

```
myApp.controller('myCtrl',['$scope', 'AWS', function myCtrl($scope, AWS){
AWS.config.update({
```

The point of the array is to explicitly register your dependencies as a string so that angular knows what they are. You don't always have to provide the array but if you ever minify your code angular won't know what dependencies you're injecting.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the AWS module to your app [module](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module), for example

```
myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['AWS']);
```

**Edit:**
And as noted by Ephapox, correct the order of your controller parameters

```
myApp.controller('myCtrl',['$scope', 'AWS', function myCtrl($scope, AWS){
```